# Categorical sampling without instantiating probability vector

Tags: categorical-data, sampling, discrete-distributions

I want to sample from a discrete distribution with probability vector $p \in \mathbb R^n$, where $n$ is large.

Suppose that $p_i = f_i / Z$, where $Z$ is a normalization constant. I can compute the elements $f_i$ easily, but instantiating the full vector of the $f_i$ (or the $p_i$) is expensive in terms of computer memory.

Is there an algorithm to sample from $p$ without instantiating the full probability vector? Suppose you are able to make several passes over the $f_i$.

Comment: Is anything known about the $p$'s (even bounds may be useful)? For example, is it unimodal? (and if so, do we know the mode?) Can we identify the most probable $i$ values?

Comment: @Glen_b No. But I don't mind traversing the values of $p_i$ several times. I just want to avoid allocating the full array of values in memory.

Comment: The most general case is hard and any additional information may lead to huge speedups. On that most general case, would something of the order of $\sqrt{n}$ random variable values and their probabilities be small enough to fit easily in memory?

Comment: Oh, and is there a lot of variation in size of $p_i$ values (say at least a couple of orders of magnitude between a large $p$ and a small $p$), or is there not much variation? (less than say an order of magnitude)

Comment: Is your access to the full list of elements sequential (like on tape) or is 'random access' possible? (in the computing sense, not the statistical sense, like on disk)

Comment: Are the $f$'s obtained from some easily stated formula or is their value more complicated (say from some algorithm, or based on some enormous number of binned observations)

Comment: @Glen_b For the scenario I have in mind, you can assume that you can compute the $f_i$  at any time, not necessarily in order (that is, 'random access' is possible). The $f_i$ are computed with an algorithm, from data. I would like to avoid any allocations that would scale with $n$ somehow.

Comment: I understand that there is a lot to specify here. If my question is still too ambiguous, I would appreciate at least some pointers to names of algorithms of this sort so I can look them up.

Comment: @Glen_b In case you are interested, I found an answer (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general this is called [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).
For this particular question, there is a detailed explanation of how to implement an "online sampler":

http://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/08/01/gumbel-max-trick-and-weighted-reservoir-sampling/